# Regex to match either 2 or 3 words, but not 1 word

Tags: java, regex

Im currently using the following regex to check that the input is 2 or 3 words only. The words should not contain any numerical values.

```
^\s*([a-zA-Z]+\s*){2,3}$
```

This however allows the input "Tommy" (1 word) to be allowed when it should not be.

Thank you

Comment: Make the `+` quantifier possessive `++`. Or change your group `(...)` to an atomic group `(?>...)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement word boundaries as in

```
^\s*(?:(?:\b[a-zA-Z]+\b)\s*){2,3}$
#         -^-        -^-
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/J4gb86/2).

Comment: This disallows "Tommy" but allows "tommy tes4t"

Comment: @benjo456: Right, change `\w+` to `[a-zA-Z]+` then.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this regex to match 2 or 3 words separated by a horizontal space:

```
^\h*[a-zA-Z]+\h+[a-zA-Z]+(?:\h+[a-zA-Z]+)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ayR3SD/1)

You can also use `split` function and check the length:

```
String[] words = input.split("\\h+"):
if (words.length == 2 || words.length == 3) {
    // 2 or 3 words found
}
```

Comment: `\h` is supported starting from Java 8 which is fairly old since Java 9 is also out.

Comment: Sorry, did not know that.